# why after execute a successful bigquery insert it is stored in a temporal table?

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

hello I pushed some rows into a  bigquery table as follows:

```
errors = client.insert_rows("course-big-query-python.api_data_set_course_33.my_table_aut33",[string_tuple], selected_fields = schema2)
assert errors == []
```

however when I verify the result at the visual interface I see that the actual table size is 0,

[image]

I verify the Streaming buffer statistics there is the table successfully inserted:

[image]

I also excecuted a query to the table and the result is appearing stored in a temporal table as follows:

[image]

So I would like to appreciate support to insert the table in the corresponding place rather than a temporary table

Comment: This is expected behavior: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#missingunavailable-data. Your data will be automatically consolidated in the regular table eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load data in BigQuery, you can either stream or batch it in.

If you choose streaming, data will go straight into a temporal space until it gets consolidated into the table.

You can find a longer description of how a streaming insert works here:

- https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/life-of-a-bigquery-streaming-insert

[image]

If you want to batch instead of stream, use [`jobs.load`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load) instead of `insert_row`.